# Including cluster variable in multiple regression using "many models" code

Tags: r

I have a multiple linear regression model for which the outcome variables are 30 biomarkers and the predictor variable fitness adjusted for age, sex, and adiposity. Having used the "many models" approach advocated by Hadley Wickham, I have the below code that performs the same regression for each of the 30 biomarkers and then uses the `broom` package to extract the relevant summary statistics.

What I would like to include in my model is a cluster variable for `school` as my data was collected from students across 61 schools. From reading online it seems the `multiwayvcov` package is appropriate, but I can't figure out how to write this into the many models code.

```
#select regression variables from dataframe
variables <- dataframe %>%
  select(sex, age, adiposity, fitness, biomarker1 : biomarker30)


#regression
reg_model <- variables %>%
  gather(outcome_name, outcome_value, -(sex : andersen)) %>%
  group_by(outcome_name) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(outcome_value ~ fitness + adiposity + sex + age, data =.)))


#model summaries and estimate
summaries <- reg_model %>%
  mutate(glance = map(model, broom::glance),
     tidy = map(model, broom::tidy)
  )

#unnest
glance <- unnest(summaries, glance, .drop = TRUE)
tidy <- unnest(summaries, tidy)
```

If anybody has any advice regarding this I'd be really grateful. Thanks!

Comment: You ask for "any advice regarding this". What is "this"? Are you asking about your code? If so can you be more specific about what the problem is. If you are asking about the most appropriate statistical method for your data, then that type of question belongs on [stats.se], not here. You don't just choose a function to apply to your data, you choose an appropriate statistical method and then find which method does that.

Comment: Thanks for replying. "....regarding this..." is in reference to how to including a cluster variable in my linear regression analysis, which uses the above code.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by adding a cluster variable into your linear regression. What exactly is the type of model you are trying to run? How are you modeling the mean and variance?

Comment: There are 30 biomarkers. A multiple linear regression model is performed for each biomarker i.e. lm(biomarkerA ~ fitness + adiposity + sex + age) I would like to include a cluster variable as the data was collected from students at 61 different schools, and I am trying to account for a potential clustering effect that the students in some schools may be more physically fit than in others e.g. because they might attend a specialised sports college.

Comment: But what is that cluster variable supposed to do? Are you trying to fix a mixed model? Allow for some random intercept for each school? You need to choose some way to model the clustering effect. This still doesn't make sense from a statistical point of view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but you can use [`estimatr::lm_robust()`](https://declaredesign.org/r/estimatr) to easily cluster your standard errors and it plays well with `broom::tidy()`. I also don't have your data, but the following should work fine:

```
#regression
reg_model <- variables %>%
  gather(outcome_name, outcome_value, -(sex : andersen)) %>%
  group_by(outcome_name) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm_robust(outcome_value ~ fitness + adiposity + sex + age, data =., clusters = school)))
```